# Spring MVC set global DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want my `controllers` to parse dates in `RequestParams` and `PathVariables` according to a standard format.

Is it possible to set an application-wide `@DateTimeFormat` without annotating every `@RequestParam` individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it at the controller level. Add `@initBinder` in your controller and it will format the date according to the given formatter.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    // true passed to CustomDateEditor constructor means convert empty String to null
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Not part of the original question but, is there a way to override this for individual request params? It seems that DateTimeFormat gets ignored when I use InitBinder.

Comment: I do not see a way to do that. There might be a way but i am not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible by Spring AOP but how would you tell your code if you have different keys for date in request. but check following link for more derails:

[Spring AOP Advice on Annotated Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310115/spring-aop-advice-on-annotated-controllers)